# Select value of selection field from javascript in odoo 12

Tags: javascript, select, odoo

I want to select the value of the selection field using javascript or jquery in odoo 12. e.g. I have a value of selection from javascript I want to select or set the value of the selection field. For that I am writing the following code :

```
var type_option = result['type'];
$('.select_question select').find('option[value="free_text"]').show();
$('.select_question select').val('option[value="free_text"]');          
$('.select_question select').val(type_option);
$('.select_question select').text(type_option);
```

But in selection field value is not selected. can any one please help.

**Update**

```
var FieldMany2ManyTags = relationalField.FieldMany2ManyTags.include({   
    supportedFieldTypes: ['selection'],
    events: _.extend({}, relationalField.FieldMany2ManyTags.prototype.events, {
        'click .badge': '_onClickTag',
    }),

    _onClickTag: function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        var self = this;
        var id = $(event.target).parent().data('id');

        var data = this._rpc({
            model: 'survey.survey',
            method: 'get_id',
            args: [id],
        }).then(function (result) { 


            //Display Question In question field
            $('.question_class').val(result['question']);   

            //Show selection field
            var type_option = result['type'];//selection field value
            var type_option = result['type'];
            $('.select_question select').find('option[value="free_text"]').show();
            $('.select_question select').val('option[value="free_text"]');          
            $('.select_question select').val(type_option);
            $('.select_question select').text(type_option);             


            //For check Box 
            $('.mandatory_class .custom-control-input input').val(result['constr_mandatory']);

            if(result['constr_mandatory'] === true){

                 var $checkbox = $('.custom-control-input');
                         $checkbox.prop('checked', true);

                if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
                            $('.mandatory_msg_class').val(result['constr_error_msg']);
                    $('.o_form_label').show();                  
                    $('.mandatory_msg_class').show();       
                     }
            }else{

                var $checkbox = $('.custom-control-input');
                         $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
                if ($checkbox.not(':checked')) {                                    
                    $('.mandatory_msg_class').hide();           
                     }//close if
            }

        });

        return data;

    },
});//close FieldMany2ManyTags
```

[image]

Comment: Odoo stores the values in object they are called widgets, I don't think you can do that using the html component you need to call `set_value` of the widget. Can you show your code and what are you doing exactly

Comment: Thanks, @CharifDZ for your comment. I have updated my question, added code with a screenshot. The purpose of doing this is to a selection of a value from javascript if I am Click on tags of many2many field. I am able to achieve click event on many2many_tags widget and also able to show other field but for selection field nothing will happen. Can you please help?

Comment: Also is it possible to call the function of one widget to another?

Comment: You want to go from a field in one2many to the parent model?! Very challenging thing to do. I will try to help with this but i'm not that good in JavaScript specially in Odoo

Comment: I think I found a solution for your problem, I will fix some issue with it and post my answer tomorrow, you still working on this requirement or you all ready found a solution for it?

Comment: Yes, I am still working on this requirement. I am checking after a click on one widget call another widget function and also I am waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a field value you need to trigger Odoo event `field_change` passing the record ID that you want to change and the field that will be changed along with some option for other fields:

```js
    // this is the widget object
    this.trigger_up('field_changed', 
                    dataPointID: this.dataPointID,
                    changes: changes, // change is an object {field_name: value, other_field_name: value}
                    viewType: this.viewType});
```

This event is handled by the `BasicModel` at the end to update each record.

In you example things is more complicated because you want to go from a field in your one2many to the parent model, unfortunately in the widget of the question field we don't have the ID of the parent record only the ID of the page model or whatever is called. so I used a new custom odoo event (I named it `badge_clicked`) to handle it from the parent widget (`One2many field widget`) in this widget we have the ID of the parent record. Hope comments clears things for you:

```
/*
   Handle event trigged by the method that handle the badge click event
*/
FieldX2Many.include({
    custom_events: _.extend({}, FieldX2Many.prototype.custom_events, {
          badge_clicked: '_OnBadgeClicked',
    }),
    _OnBadgeClicked : function(ev){
        // do this only in edit mode
        if (this.mode != 'edit')
                return undefined;

        var result = ev.data.result; 
        var changes = {};
        // this will trigger an update on the field it self,
        // odoo will wait for the type of operation

        //Display Question In question field ( I don't know the field names)
        // Very Big Note: the values must be valid you cannot give an interger value to char field for example
        changes['field_name'] = result['question'];
        changes['some_other_field'] = result['some_ther_field_to_set'];
        // if you want to check some field of the current record don't use JQuery to retrieve the value use the record attribute of the widget.
        // if (this.record.data['some_field'] === 'some_value'){
        //        do some thing
        // }      

        // this is required(a dummy update to avoid unexpected behavior by the field_changed event)
        changes[this.name] = {
                operation: 'UPDATE',
                id: ev.data.dataPointID,
                changes: {} };


        // we did all of this just to trigger the field_changed from the One2many field because in the many2many tags we don't have the ID of the parent record.
        this.trigger_up('field_changed', {
            dataPointID: this.dataPointID,  // here the ID is the parent(global) record
            changes: changes,
            viewType: this.viewType});
     },
});

/*
   Handle click event to inform the parent widget.
*/
FieldMany2ManyTags.include({
    events: _.extend({}, FieldMany2ManyTags.prototype.events, {
        'click .badge': '_onClickTag',
    }),
     _onClickTag: function(event){
            var self = this;
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            // deactivate this for other model.
            // I tried the same thing with account.invoice and it worked perfectly
            // I don't know the name of the model in your one2many field in my case is invoice.line ^^
            if (self.model != 'account.invoice.line')
                return undefined;
            var self = this;
        var id = $(event.target).parent().data('id');

        var data = this._rpc({
            model: 'survey.survey',
            method: 'get_id',
            args: [id],
        }).then(function (result) { 
           // trigger an event that will be handled by the parent widget
           self.trigger_up('badge_clicked', {
                result: result,
                // when we click the One2many field in edit mode, a field_change will be trigger
                // we need the ID of this record to trigger a dummy update
                dataPointID: self.dataPointID,  // here the ID is the record in the line of one2many field and we don't have the ID of the parent record at this point this why we are triggering this event to be handled by the one2many
           });
        }
     },
});
```

**Note**: I tried this and it worked perfectly I changed the `comment` field of the invoice model by clicking on the `tax` tags, the Idea is to trigger an Odoo event from the click event handler and handle that event at the parent widget witch is `one2many` to be able to trigger `field_change` event using the correct `ID`. I hope you this helps you

Comment: start with simple code like updating a text field in the parent record, and remember the values must be valid, not integer value for char field

Comment: Thank You So Much @Charif DZ for your help. Solution provided by you working as per I want. Thanks for your valuable time and solution

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer as a correct answer. Glade that you understood the idea.

Comment: Yes Sure. Your answer is accepted for correct answer and also upvote for your answer.

Comment: I want your help. As per your solution, able to open many2many_tags record in the parent view, but now after doing some change, I want to update record in the database and in many2many_tags also. For that, I have created one button in the XML file and one python method. In the python method, I have used orm write method, to update records in a database.

Comment: But after calling method by using javascript, the record is not received. It takes false value. can you please help for doing the same.

Comment: Please ask another question and explain more, and with some screenshots if possible? I didn't understand what you want